# insertion of date to mysql via php from ios = 0000-00-00

Tags: php, ios, mysql, insert

I'm trying to insert some data from my iOS app to a database set up with phpmyadmin. It is working nearly fine, the problem I have is that one entry allways gets timestamp `0000-00-00`. I tried to update this entry, but this never happens.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)update
{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

// NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSString *authCredentials = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"xxxxxxxxx", @"xxxxxxxxxxx"];

NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",[authCredentials base64EncodedStringWithWrapWidth:0]];

[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request

 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
 NSData * data,
 NSError * error){

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSUserDefaults*prefs=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString * a=[prefs objectForKey:@"user"];

NSString *b=[prefs objectForKey:@"expiration_date_full"];

NSString* c=[prefs objectForKey:@"expiration_date_werbung"];

NSString *noteDataString = [NSString    stringWithFormat:@"user=%@&expiration_date_full=%@&expiration_date_werbung=%@",    a,b,c];

                           [request setHTTPBody:[noteDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                          if (!error){

NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration     defaultSessionConfiguration];
 NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:     defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
                               NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =    [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *dataRaw, NSURLResponse *header, NSError *error) {
                                   NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                                         JSONObjectWithData:dataRaw
                                                         options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                                   NSString *status = json[@"status"];

                                   if([status isEqual:@"1"]){
                                       NSLog(@"upload erfolgt");
                                   } else {
                                       NSLog(@"upload failed");
                                   }
                               }];


 [dataTask resume];


  }

 }

];}
```

The call of update:

```
UserLoader *loader=[[UserLoader alloc] init]
[loader update];

NSLog(@"loader started");
```

The .php file:

```
<?php
$verbindung =     mysqli_connect("xxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","v8.xxxxxxxxxxxx    xxxx");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$user = ($_POST['user']);
$expiration_date_full = ($_POST['expiration_date_full']);
$expiration_date_werbung = ($_POST['expiration_date_werbung']);
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($verbindung, "SELECT user FROM table user = ?")){
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $user);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $havetoinput);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
if($havetoinput == ""){
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($verbindung, "INSERT INTO table (user,     expiration_date_full, expiration_date_werbung) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $user, $expiration_date_full,     $expiration_date_werbung);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}  
}else{
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($verbindung, "UPDATE table SET     expiration_date_full = ?, expiration_date_werbung = ? WHERE user = ?")){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $expiration_date_full,     $expiration_date_werbung, $user);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}        
}
mysqli_close($verbindung);
?>
```

And the result: 
[image]

Comment: So have you checked the format of the date values your server-side script receives …?

Comment: It's not a problem about the format I think, because both entries you can see there in the picture were send by app.

Comment: PS: Why allways downvote my questions? Stack don't want people ask questions here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your database structure, but i think that when you bind params on user key it should be `i` in `ss` + `i`, and make sure that the column types are compatible with what you are inserting if you want to insert a string in a datetime column it could be formated in other ways use `STR_TO_DATE()` before converting it to `datetime`

`UPDATE table SET expiration_date_full = STR_TO_DATE(?, '%Y-%m-%d'), expiration_date_werbung = STR_TO_DATE(?, '%Y-%m-%d') WHERE user = ?"`